# Managing Echart selection using API

Tags: echarts

I use Echarts library to draw a bar chart. I set [`selectedMode`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-bar.selectedMode)=`single` and utilize Echats' `select`->[`itemStyle`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-bar.select.itemStyle) option.

My users can switch selected bars by clicking them, everything works fine. Clicking on the selected bar effectively unselect it.

How can I manage echarts bar chart selection using my own external controls?

I.e., I have a button "Clear selection". What API or option of my Echart can I use?

A chart option example:

```
option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [
    {
      data: [120, 200, 150, 80, 70, 110, 130],
      type: 'bar',
      selectedMode: 'single',
      select: {
        itemStyle: {
          color: '#FF0000'
        }
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [chart actions](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#action.select) to select or unselect specific items. Unselecting all data items in your example could look like this:

```js
myChart.dispatchAction({
    type: 'unselect',
    seriesIndex: 0,
    dataIndex: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6],
})
```